# Two tables do not align vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{3mm}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want to create two tables that are on top of each other. However, the bottom table is aligned slightly to the right of the top table. The difference is small, but noticeable. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to leave a blank line before `\vspace{3mm}`, not after it. On the other hand, you can also use only one `tabular` and add the vertical space with `\\[3mm]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3mm}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

Or

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\[3mm]
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice puzzle, but there is an explanation.

1. The end-of-line after `\end{tabular}` counts as a space
2. The blank line after `\vspace{3mm}` is the same as `\par`.

Thus we can examine the situation as if it was

```
\mbox{X} \vspace{3mm}\par
```

as there's no conceptual difference between a tabular and a box.

Since `\vspace` is found when TeX is still making a paragraph, the `\@bsphack`–`\@esphack` mechanism comes into play. This mechanism is used to avoid inserting more spaces than wanted when commands like `\linebreak[2]` are processed. Since `\vspace{3mm}` has a space in front of it, TeX will ignore spaces that follow, based on the rules governing `\@bsphack`–`\@esphack`; but the same rules imply that a glob of zero glue is inserted after `\vspace{3mm}`.

So we have this:

```
X<normal space><vadjust item><zero space>\par
```

(where `<vadjust item>` means the vertical space that will be considered *after* the paragraph is split into lines). Now `\par` is executed, which kills the last glob of glue (the zero space), but the normal space between X and the `<vadjust item>` remains.

This space is responsible for the slight, but noticeable misalignment.

Solution: use `\vspace` ***after*** a blank line whenever possible; in some cases it has its advantages using it inside a paragraph, but never as the last item in a paragraph.

Comment: Very nice explanation. You are one of the good teachers I have seen. :)